# here maps doesn't show up on HTTPS pages

Tags: html, http, https, here-api

I just started using here-maps i.s.o. google-maps.
The script works perfectly using file:///path/index.html. But when I upload it to the server that runs HTTPS  the map isn't displayed. Firefox console tells me:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content“http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js”[Learn More]
```

...

Changing "http" into "https" in the html-code doesn't help.

here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
      <script>
        // Initialize the platform object:
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'app_id': 'myappid',
            'app_code': 'myappcode'
        });

        // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
        var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

        // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
        var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
        });

        // Create a marker consisting of a blue "M"
        var svgMarkup = '<svg width="24" height="24" ' +
             'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
             '<rect stroke="white" fill="#a2ccff" x="1" y="1" width="22" ' +
             'height="22" /><text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" ' +
             'font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" ' +
             'fill="white">M</text></svg>';

        // Create an icon, an object holding the latitude and longitude, and a marker:
        var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup),
            coords = {lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4},
            marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: icon});

        // Add the marker to the map and center the map at the location of the marker:
        map.addObject(marker);
        map.setCenter(coords);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, thank you!. This did the trick: added the useHTTPS flag to the platform variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the whole example might be too much. The main issue with the code above is that the JS API need to be loaded also via https:

```
<head>

    <title>Simple HERE Map Display</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/assets/hereAccount-21ef8922d5d04b494504bc6295d247bc781e0cf2542e5d071c63dd282590abdb.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css">
    <script src="https://account.here.com/js/sdk/sso.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app_id = "here goes your key",
            app_code = "here goes your key";
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    [...]
```

Comment: I don't get it why  `'useHTTPS': true` needs to be added for platform config. Why isn't it the default? Other mapping libraries can detect if they are loaded via https or not, there is no need for an extra configuration step to configure it, besides loading the api with the appropriate protocol.

Comment: HTTPS is supported too. Please have a look at this example:
https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/simple_map